# Django - How to combine two queries after doing a group by

Tags: python, django

GOAL: Group by ITEM all INCOMING and its OUTGOING then SUM the quantity to come up with a simple table in my template like this:

```
Item        | Total In | Total Out| Stock
1. Cement   | 400      | 300      | 100
```

My models.py

```
class Incoming(models.Model):
    ...
    project_site = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSite, related_name='in_project_site', default=7, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_in', null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.DecimalField('Quantity', db_index=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    ...

class Outgoing(models.Model):
    ...
    base_in = models.ForeignKey('warehouse.Incoming', related_name='out', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField('Quantity', db_index=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    ...
```

Okay so the goal is to group all incoming by ITEM, then annotate the current total Incoming and Outgoing. So naturally I did this in my views.py

```
 incoming = Incoming.objects.filter(project_site__id=self.object.id)

 context['inventory'] =  incoming.values('item__item_name')\
    .annotate(tot_in=Sum('quantity'))\
    .annotate(tot_out=Sum('out__quantity'))
```

This does not give the proper SUM for the total_in, now after some search this is apparently an issue. One suggestion I found was to separate the query into to so this is what I did.

```
context['current_in'] =  incoming.values('item__item_name').annotate(tot_in=Sum('quantity'))
context['current_out'] =  incoming.values('item__item_name').annotate(tot_out=Sum('out__quantity'))
```

This gives me the correct SUM for each In and Out, now my problem is how to UNITE/COMBINE the two again so I could easily loop through it on my template? I did a search and tried the following to no luck.

```
list(chain(pagelist1, pagelist2))
# This does not combine items with same ITEM name. The output for this is
Item        | Total In | Total Out| Stock
Cement      | 400      |          | 
Cement      |          | 300      |
```

doing a UNION doesn't help either. Any help would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
incoming.values('item__item_name').annotate(tot_in=Sum('quantity'), tot_out=Sum('out__quantity'))
```

If it does not work then but you can use pythonic approach here using [**`zip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

current_in = incoming.values('item__item_name').annotate(tot_in=Sum('quantity'))
current_out = incoming.values('item__item_name').annotate(tot_out=Sum('out__quantity'))
context['current'] = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(current_in, current_out, fillvalue={})]
```

Comment: Your first suggestion gives the same output when chaining annotations. Same as my first query. Your second suggestion provides me with the correct SUM, but for some reason when I try to loop over it on my template, it seems to populate my table horizontally not downwards. How do we format this into a queryset so I could do more stuffs like filtering?

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, how do you people know those libraries? I guess I still have a lot of stuffs to learn.

Comment: when you put stuff in zip, it turns into a generator, and iterating it makes it a list. You can run [`python filter()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) here, but you can't run django filter here.